# Многомодульный проект

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Есть проект (веб + андроид приложение) со следующей структурой:

```
android-app
    // Android app here
server-app
    dist
    license_generator
    src
        server-core
            // simple Java app
        server-web
            // Spring app
client
    dist
    src
        // angular app here
```

**Как настроить IDEA для работы с данным проектом?** Пока получилось открыть каждый "модуль" как отдельный проект (server-core, server-web, client.src открывал отдельно). Пробывал открывать по-другому, идея не видит зависимостей (иногда даже не видит классы). Но так работать крайне не удобно.

Comment: Вероятно вам нужен проект сборки на gradle

Comment: @JK_Action не совсем понял что Вы имеете ввиду, gradle используется для сборки "каждого модуля", но общего build.gradle нету.

Comment: Вам нужен gradle проект с вложенными подпроектами, предполагаю что из всех систем сборки java он вероятнее всего поддерживает js(webpack)

Comment: @JK_Action вероятно вы не поняли: в данном проекте ВСЕ подпроекты используют gradle для сборки (кроме приложения на ангуляре), но корневого файла gradle.build нету